# What is the largest distance that still guarantees a linear time distance search?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, search-problem

Suppose we have two sorted arrays *A* and *B* consisting of unique real numbers. We want to find all pairs of the form (*a* $\in$ *A*, *b* $\in$ *B*) such that, for some *c* $\in R+$, their absolute difference $\mid$*a - b*$\mid$ $\lt$ *c*.

If *c* is 0, we can linearly search the two sorted arrays for exact matches. If *c* is arbitrarily large, we need to return all pairs that exist between the two arrays, which is an $n^2$ search.  My question is whether there exists a function $c_{max} = f(A, B)$ that, given the two arrays, finds the largest c for which all pairs with difference less than c can still be found in linear time.

This is a problem I've been thinking about while messing around with improving an algorithm, so I don't have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a straightforward algorithm for your original problem, based on a linear scan through the array with two pointers, one to $a$ and the other to the largest $b$ such that $|a-b|<c$.  The running time will be linear in the number of pairs $a,b$ that need to be output.

So, this answers your question in the positive: if $c$ is small enough that the number of such pairs is $O(n)$, then the running time will be $O(n)$.

Comment: Right, I agree with you. I guess a way to rephrase my question would be this: Does there exist a function such that, given *A* and *B*, it returns the largest c for which the number of such pairs is in $O(n)$?

Comment: @AndrewDraganov, yes, there does - you just specified such a function!  (Assuming we replace the asymptotic $O(n)$ with a concrete value.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that such a function likely exists, and am more interested in the form that it takes. Given the values in *A* and *B* (and the time complexity *n*), what does the function look like that returns the maximum c? Do the means of *A* and *B* come into play? The variances? Something else? Things along those lines. Sorry if my initial question was too vague.

Comment: @AndrewDraganov, if you're asking about the mathematical function, you've already defined it.  That's what it looks like.  A function is just a mapping; it doesn't necessarily have to be in some algebraic form, or be limited to only using information like the variance.  This doesn't sound like a research-level question about theoretical computer science.